# Specifying columns using cellspace

Tags: tables, columns

I'm using cellspace to try get some more padding around fractions in tables and I'm stuck on this gibberish:

```
\begin{tabular}[b]{ >{}l*{2}{| >{$}Sc <{$}}}
```

What does it all mean? For reference, I'm used to the following:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
```

I read the manual and it doesn't mention the first type of syntax.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) You haven't told us which manual you've read. :) That syntax is described in (I believe) _The LaTeX Companion_ and also the [`array` package documentation](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/array).

Comment: Oh righto. I read the cellspace manual. What is that notation called?

Comment: That bit of code is typically referred to as the tabular preamble (or tabular preamble options).

Comment: It uses the `array` package syntax: `*{2}{column specifier}` means two copies of this column specifier; >{$} says to enter math mode at the beginning of the cell — and `<{$}` of course says to leave math mode on quitting the cell. As to `S`, it is the pre-specifier  from the `cellspace` package. You should take a look at the packages doc for details.

Comment: Thanks Paul and especially Bernard for the specifics. Understood!

Comment: @Bernard care to answer?

Comment: @Paul Gessler: OK, it can be useful to beginners.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some explanations:

```
\begin{tabular}[b]{ >{}l*{2}{| >{$}Sc <{$}}}
```

uses the `array` package syntax:

- `[b]` means will be bottom-aligned with the rest of the line. The default is `[c]` and you also have it top-aligned (`[t]`).
- `>{some code}` is code to be executed at the beginning of each cell in a column, as `<{some code}` is to be executed at the end. Here `>{$}` means ‘entering math mode’.
- `Sc` means the column will be centred, and will ensure a minimal vertical spacing above and below each cell in this column (the pre-qualifier `S` comes from `cellspace`).
- `*{2}{some qualifier(s)}` means some column type (or some pattern of column types) is to be inserted twice.

So, in the present case, we'll have a left-aligned column, a vertical rule, a centred column in math mode with some vertical padding, another vertical rule and another column of  the previous type.